How can one tell if equilibrium points are attractors in optimization?
Consider equilibrium problems in the context of optimization, ie, finding $(\overline{x},\overline{y})\in \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$\overline{x} \in \arg\min \{f_x(x,\overline{y}); \quad x \in C_x\subset\mathbb{R}^n\}$$
and
$$\overline{x} \in \arg\min \{f_y(\overline{x},y); \quad y \in C_y\subset\mathbb{R}^n\}$$
for some sets $C_i$ and functions $f_i$, $i=x,y$.
Given an equilibrium point $(\overline{x},\overline{y})$ how can one tell it is an attractor? (i.e., if I run an algorithm for finding equilibrium points and select the initial point close enough to such point it will converge to such point)?
I know that there are notions of attractor and stability for equilibrium points in the context of ODEs, but I don't know if those exist in the context of optimization. Is there a way to know such property in advance?
